# How do I get the 10.13.6 update to (reboot and) install?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mac-appstore, software-update

I have macOS 10.13.4 on my Mac.  In the App Store, it shows 10.13.6 as an available Software Update.

When I click the "Update" button, I get the notification in the top-right corner of my screen:

```
Restarting Your Computer
                                             [Restart]
Your computer will restart in 43 seconds     [ Later ]
to install updates.
```

When I click "Restart" (or wait for a minute), the App Store window shows a sheet that says:

```
Available updates have changed.
Click "Show Details" to see the available updates.

                           ( Cancel ) ( Show Details )
```

This aborts the restart.  If I click "Cancel", the sheet goes away, and the reboot doesn't happen.  If I click "Show Details", the sheet goes away, and the reboot doesn't happen.

If I quit the App Store first and then click "Restart", it opens the App Store again and shows me this sheet.

If I quit the App Store and choose plain "Restart" from the Apple menu, it restarts my Mac, but doesn't install the update.

How do you install the 10.13.6 update on 10.13.4?  What am I missing?

Comment: On what Mac hardware are you attempting this on?

Comment: @Allan: It's a Mac Pro (2010?), but I'm not sure how that's relevant.

Comment: It could have been if it was a Hackintosh.  You can also try downloading and installing it manually from [Apple Downloads](https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads/macos)

Comment: Got the Apple logo on the side and everything.  Downloading the combo update now...